# What happens to the existing data of Android user preferences when preferences structure changes in a new version?

Tags: android, preferences, updates

For example, if a few entries of preferences are added or deleted, how does Android handle the existing preference data when the app is updated with the new preferences structure?

I am sorry for this rudimentary question, but my diligent search and reading could not find the answer.

Comment: You could pull the prefs XML file from DDMS and look for yourself, if you wish

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shared preferences are stored in the xml file in the folder `data/data/your.application.package/shared_prefs/`. The file is called `your.application.package_preferences.xml`;

When you retrieve the shared preferences, you call the [Context.getSharedPreferences](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,int%29) method. It creates the `SharedReferences` object and invokes the [SharedReferences.startLoadFromDisk](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#SharedPreferencesImpl.startLoadFromDisk%28%29) method.

If you open this method, you will see that the xml file with preferences (`mFile`) is parsed and preferences are loaded into the memory storage (`map`).

```
BufferedInputStream str = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(mFile), 16*1024);
map = XmlUtils.readMapXml(str);
```

From then you will always read your preferences from the memory. More exactly from the `private Map<String, Object> mMap` variable.
Also the application can call the [startReloadIfChangedUnexpectedly](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#SharedPreferencesImpl.startReloadIfChangedUnexpectedly%28%29) method and if the underlying file has been changed, it will be parsed and a new HashMap will be created.

As to your question, there are the following cases:

1. You added a preference item in a new version. Then the default value specified as the second parameter will be returned. Note: the attribute android:defaultValue is not used, so be aware.

   `String v = (String)mMap.get(key); // not found => v = null`

   `return v != null ? v : defValue; // return defValue`
2. You removed a preference item in a new version. The xml file and `map` object will contain some redundant data, but it will be fixed when the user saves preferences next time.
3. You changed the key of a preference item to some key which wasn't used. Then the default value will be returned. The same result as p.1.
4. You removed one preference item (with the key `pref1_key`, for example) and changed the key of another item so that it refers to the first item (from `pref2_key` to `pref1_key`). Then the second preference item will have the value of the first item.
5. You changed a type of a preference item (from boolean to int, for example). Then it will throw the CastException because of this and similar code: `(Integer)mMap.get(key);`. But you can change, for example, EditTextPreference to ListPreference, because they both have the String type.

Maybe there are some more test cases, but so far I've made up only 5.

Also here is the example of the preferences file with ListPreference, EditTextPreference and CheckBoxPreference:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="pref_theme_key">THEME_LIGHT</string>
    <string name="pref_homepage_key">test</string>
    <boolean name="pref_display_name_key" value="true" />
</map>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer.  Your listed cases were exactly what on my mind. I thought changing preferences structure was a fairly common scenario during app development, but could not find anything addressing it in the Android document.  Maybe, I was not looking at the right document.

Comment: @Hong Sometimes there are no information in the official documentation, that's why I use the grepcode website and examine the source code myself.

Answer (score 2):

> how does Android handle the existing preference data when the app is updated with the new preferences structure?

It is unclear what you mean by "preferences structure".

You can think of a `SharedPreferences` as being a persistent `HashMap`. You store various values under various keys, and you can get them back later. Android has no *a priori* knowledge of the keys or the types of values that will be stored under those keys, until you actually store something.

My guess is that by "preference structure", you mean "preference screen definitions in XML". In that case:

- if you add new preferences, Android will handle those normally, just as if the preferences has been around all along but the user had never set those preferences before
- if you remove preferences that you had used before, the old data remains, unless you elect to get rid of it, as Android has no way to know that you will never use that data again
- if you re-key a preference (i.e., replace `keyA` with `key1` for what logically is the same preference), Android will treat `key1` as a totally new preference, and so you will need to put smarts in your code somewhere to update your `SharedPreferences` data to reflect the key change, if you so choose

There is no `SharedPreferencesOpenHelper` equivalent of `SQLiteOpenHelper` to manage preference "schema versions" and help you migrate data. You are welcome to create such a system, if you so choose, if you feel that it will help you manage frequently-changing "preference structure".